# Define a sentence that has arbitrarily large finite models

Tags: logic, model-theory

I am trying to solve these problems :

(a) Define a $V_G$-sentence $\phi$ such that $\phi$ has arbitrarily large finite models, and for any model $G$, $G$ is a connected graph.

(b) Find a connected graph that does not model the sentence $\phi$ you found 
in (a).

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you clarify what $V$ is?

Comment: $V$ is the vocabulary over $G$, so actually we are looking for a $V_{G}$-sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof that graph connectedness is not expressible in the first-order language of graphs is a classic application of compactness.  The purpose of this exercise is to show that a first-order sentence in the language of graphs may only have connected models, as long as it excludes some connected graphs as well.

This observation suggests how to proceed.  A sentence about graphs that has connected models of arbitrary size is one that characterizes complete (simple) graphs.  If $E$ is the edge relation, then

$$ \forall x \,.\, \neg E(x,x) \wedge \forall y \,.\, x=y \vee E(x,y) \enspace.$$

Every connected but incomplete graph is not a model of this sentence.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Just one last question to be sure, what this symbol, $.$, mean in your sentence. Is it multiplication?

Comment: No, the dot, borrowed from lambda calculus, separates the quantifier (e.g., $\forall x$) from the expression that is its scope.  There's plenty of different notations in use for quantification formulae.  An alternative to the one above would be $(\forall x)(\neg E(x,x) \wedge (\forall y)(x=y \vee E(x,y)))$.  Once you get used to the dots, it's a less cluttered notation.

Comment: Yes that is true!Thank you so much for your help! :-)